# Docker container sometimes gives Unknown database

Tags: php, mysql, database, docker, api

I am currently running a project on docker, and I am trying to communicate with the database via an API. They are both deployed on docker.

The problem is, when I make a call to the API (via Postman or the front-end) I SOMETIMES get a 500 error.
When I look at the logs (docker-compose logs -f) in the container folder, I get the following message

```
test-api_php | [2021-03-18 10:09:04] application.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'test-api'-#0 /app/config/....
```

the thing is, It happens like 50% of the time, the other times it works as intended. I've noticed that if I make a request and wait a few seconds, the next request is almost always going through, but if I make multiple requests consecutively, it's very unlikely to go through. I've given docker as much resources as possible 8 CPUs 12GB RAM 2GB Swap 60GB Disk Image Size.

My colleagues also have the same issue when they try it on their machine, so it's not machine specific

Comment: Are you starting and stopping your containers a lot? Are you sure your app boots up only after the database is fully operational and, if necessary, seeded? It's common with things like Docker Compose to need a moment for everything to stabilize.

Comment: @tadman I don't restart it a lot. This thing happens no matter how much time has passed since the last restart. I always make sure to initialize, migrate and seed the database when I restart, and as I said, it happens 50% of the times, like I will make a request it will go through, then I will make another one and it won't go through etc.

Comment: Hard to say based on the logs. Unless your database is somehow disappearing, or another server is taking its spot, that shouldn't happen.

Comment: @tadman I forgot to mention that this happens for any operation I am doing. For example I am using phinx for migrating and seeding, using 
`docker exec -i test-api_php vendor/bin/phinx seed:run`.
When I do that I yet again get the error. Which is why I sometimes have to even run this command 4 or 5 times in order to seed my db.
It literally makes no sense, it just disappears.

Comment: @Kimsis Sorry to revive this post but did you ever find the solution to this? I'm experiencing something similar. I have a PHP web app in a Docker container communicating with a MariaDB database in another container. The web app depends on the database. I see them both running. But all the pages of the website that require a connection to the database fail half of the time with "Unknown database..." error. If I keep refreshing, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Ok, I seem to have just fixed it by renaming the "services" in my `docker-compose.yml` file. I had the services "db" and "app" defined. I renamed them with a prefix like "myapp_db" and "myapp_app" and that seems to have fixed the connection issue. It might be a name clash with some other app I have deployed on the server. I thought only `container_name` properties had to be unique. But apparently, the service name too. I will have to check other apps to ensure service name uniqueness.